# Ping public ipv6 dns from docker container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ipv6, ping, ip-forwarding

The docker container is running on a VPS (ubuntu 18.10).

**What I am able to do:**

`ping -6 2001:4860:4860::8888` from host machine

`ping -6 <docker container ipv6 address` from host machine

`ping -6 <hosts ipv6 address>` from docker container

`ping  8.8.8.8` from docker container

**What I am not able to do:**

`ping -6 2001:4860:4860::8888` from docker container

When I execute the above command nothing happens. When I finally abort the command I got this output:

```
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 62ms
```

The docker container has an assigned ipv6 address.
What I have done so far:

```
$ip -6 route add 2001:db8:1::/64 dev docker0
$ sysctl net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding=1
$ sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

If you need any further information just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, just fixed it using this workaround:
https://github.com/robbertkl/docker-ipv6nat

- Change the ipv6 subnet to ULA-range as mentioned in the article.
- Restart the docker.service
- Run both images